# GEMI vegetation index calculation in ENVI

Tags: envi, vegetation-index

I want to calculate gemi index, but I can't write its formula in ENVI, this doesn't work.

gemi formula is:

```
(n(1−0.25n)−RED−0.1251−RED)
n = ( 2 * ( NIR ^2 - RED ^2) + 1.5 * NIR + 0.5 * RED ) / ( NIR + RED + 0.5 )
```

I bring these formulas in one, but it doesn't work:

```
(2*(b4^2-b3^2)+1.5*b4+0.5*b3)/(b4+b3+0.5)*(1-0.25*(2*(b4^2-b3^2)+1.5*b4+0.5*b3)/(b4+b3+0.5))-((b3-0.125)/(1-b3)
```

In what way I can calculate GEMI?